# Multisite WP isn't caching options when user first logs in: over 1000 SQL queries

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have a multisite WP site (WP 3.1.4, with ~300 sites). For a while now, I have noticed that the very first time someone logs in (after they have already registered), it can easily take them 10-20 seconds.

I setup monitoring using newrelic, and I see that, when a user logs in for the first time, the site queries the database with

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_?_options WHERE autoload = ?
```

over 1000 times (and several hundred times with other very similar repeating queries).

I'm pretty certain that this is being called from the wp_load_alloptions() function, which is designed to query the options once and then cache them during the remainder of the page load. (Note: I don't use any caching plugins.)

I added in some very simple "echo" logging on my test site:

```php
function wp_load_alloptions() {
        global $wpdb;

        if ( !defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) || !is_multisite() ) {
            $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        } else {
            $alloptions = false;
        }

        if ( !$alloptions ) {
            echo "<!-- alloptions cache empty -->";
            $suppress = $wpdb->suppress_errors();
            if ( !$alloptions_db = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE autoload = 'yes'" ) ) {
                echo "<!-- alloptions loading without autoload -->";
                $alloptions_db = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $wpdb->options" );
            }
            $wpdb->suppress_errors($suppress);
            $alloptions = array();
            foreach ( (array) $alloptions_db as $o ) {
                $alloptions[$o->option_name] = $o->option_value;
            }
            $size = count($alloptions);
            echo "<!-- alloptions size: {$size} -->";
            if ( !defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) || !is_multisite() ){
                echo "<!-- saving alloptions -->";
                wp_cache_add( 'alloptions', $alloptions, 'options' );
            }
        }

        return $alloptions;
    }
```

When a pre-existing user logs in, the cache works correctly: At the top of my page, I see

```
<!-- alloptions cache empty --><!-- alloptions size: 123 --><!-- saving alloptions -->
```

But when a user logs in for the first time, I see those three comments scrolling on to infinity, because $alloptions never really get saved.

Any thoughts on how to ensure that a new user's options get cached in one query, so I don't have to make 1000 queries?

Comment: What version of wordpress are you on? Are you using any persistent cache plugins?

Comment: Woops, added that to the question now. WP 3.1.4, no caching plugins.